# How can I store preferences for a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

As a simple example, let's say I want to insert a word at the bottom of every webpage, and I want the user to be able to change that word. So I have an options page (within the extension), within which I take user input and use it to call "localStorage.preferences = x;".

Next, the user navigates to http://www.google.com/, and I inject a script which writes the word found in localStorage.preferences. The problem is, since I'm now at a different domain, I'm seeing the localStorage for google.com, not my extension.

How can I share data between my extension's options page and a script injected into some 3rd-party webpage?

Comment: Its not possible as it violates the cross-domain policy. This may help somewhat : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, perhaps, the most direct response to your question, but one way to potentially get around this would be to use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to fake direct access to local storage from another domain. Assuming you're running your Javascript in the context of a content script, you could pass a message to the background page asking for a key, which would return the contents of `localStorage`.

Comment: I'm very adept with Chrome extension development, and was going to give this exact answer. Message passing is absolutely the way to go.